# Query one particular day a week, going back one year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query every Wednesday for the past year.

How can I explicitly get data from every Wednesday i.e. Oct 30, Oct 23, going back a year?

```
SELECT endOfDay as businessDate,
   CASE WHEN nodeName = 'stack' AND Name = 'overflow' THEN 'stackoverflow'
        WHEN nodeName = '84095' THEN 'Stack'
        WHEN nodeName = '42345' THEN 'Over'
        WHEN nodeName = 'FLOW' THEN 'FLOW'
        else nodeName
   END as nodeName,
   Name, Value
FROM table
WHERE endOfDay >'2018-05-30'
ORDER BY endOfDay desc
```

Comment: Add to the where clause `and datepart(weekday,endofday)=4`

Comment: yes sir. and Avery, that works nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datename func to tell whether or not it's a wednesday.

```
SELECT endOfDay as businessDate, CASE WHEN nodeName = 'stack' AND Name = 'overflow' THEN 'stackoverflow'
WHEN nodeName = '84095' THEN 'Stack'
WHEN nodeName = '42345' THEN 'Over'
WHEN nodeName = 'FLOW' THEN 'FLOW'
else nodeName
END as nodeName, Name, Value FROM table
 WHERE endOfDay > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATENAME(weekday, endOfDay) = 'Wednesday' ORDER BY endOfDay desc
```

Comment: thank you jdub, is there a way to do a year back instead of explicility saying 2018-05-30? More like should be 2018-10-31

Comment: You could use DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())  
That way no matter when you ran it, it would always be for exactly 1 year back. I'll edit my answer to include this.